# Socket connection in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I just got a error from connect API in linux.

I knew 'connect' will return zero if connection is successful, I got return value "3"

is it error code? or is there something else what don't know?

```
connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

I got value 3 from sock.

Comment: Code please. `connect()` only returns zero or -1.

Comment: Sorry I forgot put on my code

Comment: This code doesn't store a return code. How do you know it's 3? And what does 'from sock' mean?

Comment: I try to printf("%d", sock);

Comment: That is *not* a return code from `connect()`. It is one of the arguments *to* `connect()`, and it is in fact a return code from `socket()`. Your question doesn't make sense. There is no connect error evident here.

Comment: That is the assigned file descriptor number for your socket.

Comment: what dose it mean assigned file descriptor? is it connecting server successfully?

Comment: I knew what is the file descriptor I mean number of sock

Comment: When you *do* finally manage to print the return code from `connect()`, you will know whether it succeeded or not. At the moment it is anybody's guess. All you're printing now is the socket descriptor value, which is not an error. And if `connect()` returns -1 you need to call `perror()` or print `strerror()` to know why it failed.

Comment: I just did printf("%d", connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))); and I got zero. So, I did connect server successfully?

Comment: You shouldn't have to ask. This is all documented.  A return code of zero from any system call indicates success.

Comment: I was confused sock and conntect function() actually I wanted to ask about sock value but it was my mistake.

Comment: "I got the value 3 from sock" - the value in sock is *not* the value returned from connect.

Comment: It is mystifying how any confusion could possibly have arisen. The values returned by `socket()` are documented, and your question states that you already 'knew 'connect' will return zero if connection is successful'. Net content of this question is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the return value of `connect()`, it is most straight forward to use a variable that is used as the left hand side of an assignment.

```
int result = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
printf("connect returned: %d\n", result);
```

`sock` must be a socket, and was assigned a file descriptor number as a result of a call to `socket()`. Most UNIX APIs that return a new file descriptor will return the lowest available one. A program usually starts off with descriptors `0`, `1`, and `2` already in use (for STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR). So, it is not unexpected that `socket()` returned `3`.

Answer (score 0):

In linux systems (and posix generally), you can use `perror` function to know the failure reason:

```
if (0 != connect(...))
{
    perror("connect");
}
```

see [man perror](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror)